# which visual studio edition has this assembly?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

i have a .proj file in which this reference is included, but i cannot find the a appriate assembly on my disk.

Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework

which visual studio edition does this assembly include, or is there another way to get this assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... not to copy but...

That's the Visual Studio unit testing framework which is available in

- Visual Studio Team System 2005
- Visual Studio Team System 2008
- Visual Studio 2008 Professional

Note that VS 2005 Pro doesn't have it. VS 2008 Pro is actually the first non-Team system version to also have unit testing built-in.

Answer (score 1):

For 2008, Pro, Developer and Suite.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework is installed only with Team System.

Just remove this assembly from references and use any other testing framework you want.

Comment: You do if the dll is missing from your computer.